# Thymeleaf + Spring: get rid of the default element id

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is there any way to suppress auto-generating ID attribute for elements while using `th:field` in Thymeleaf (2.1.4.RELEASE)? For example, given code:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{year}" />
```

will produce the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="year" name="year" value="" />
```

What I want to achieve is (no id attribute):

```
<input type="text" name="year" value="" />
```

In JSP it was as easy as setting empty id:

```
<form:input path="year" id="" />
```

but Thymeleaf just replaces this empty attribute with the default-generated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have looked inside the source code of Thymeleaf (2.1.4.RELEASE) and the method responsible for setting element id in Spring dialect is `org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor.doProcess(...)` [(source on Github)](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/blob/2.1-master/thymeleaf-spring4/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/spring4/processor/attr/SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor.java#L147) that calls `org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.computeId(...)` [(source on Github)](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/blob/2.1-master/thymeleaf-spring4/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/spring4/processor/attr/AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java#L119). If you look at `computeId(...)`, you will see that there is no simple way to set empty id.

So we need to do it in not a simple way :) Here it is:
I created a custom dialect and defined a custom attribute `noid`. The markup looks like this:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{year}" thex:noid="true" />
```

There is a great [tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.html) explaining how to create and use custom dialects in Thymeleaf and below is the most important part: attribute processor responsible for removing id attribute from given element.

Important things to note:

- high precedence value (9999) guarantees that this processor will be executed as the last one (so no other processors will modify id after this one is executed)
- modification type is set to substitution so we are completely replacing value of id element
- removeAttributeIfEmpty(...) returns true, rather self-explanatory, remove attribute if empty
- getModifiedAttributeValues(...) sets id to empty value and because above-mentioned method returns true, id attribute is removed

Code:

```
    public class NoIdAttrProcessor extends AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor {

        public NoIdAttrProcessor() {
            super("noid");
        }

        @Override
        public int getPrecedence() {
            return 9999;
        }

        @Override
        protected ModificationType getModificationType(Arguments arguments, Element element, String attributeName, String newAttributeName) {
            return ModificationType.SUBSTITUTION;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean removeAttributeIfEmpty(Arguments arguments, Element element, String attributeName, String newAttributeName) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean recomputeProcessorsAfterExecution(Arguments arguments, Element element, String attributeName) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getModifiedAttributeValues(Arguments arguments, Element element, String attributeName) {
            Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>(1);
            values.put("id", "");
            return values;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use this in id of you input field just assign the value to only the th:name field,

```
<input type="text" th:name="*{year}" />
```

will give you output like,

```
<input type="text" name="2015" />
```

**Or** You can use a string at the end to make the id generate different from the name attribute like this

```
<input type="text" th:name="*{year}" th:id="*{year} + '-year' " />
```

will give you the output,

```
<input type="text" name="2015" id="2015-year"/>
```

Comment: The thing is that I want the name attribute to be literally equivalent to the th:field (i.e *{year} -> year, *{foo} -> foo etc.), because this is required for Spring data binding. Also setting `name="year"` is not a solution because th:field also sets value attribute automatically.